# Send TI sensor data to server

Tags: mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, iot, zigbee

I have to develop an mobile app witch should be capable to receive data from TI Sensor Tag (CC2560) through the internet.
In other words, I have multi TI sensors wich should send data (temperature, pressure...) and my app should be capable to display these data in real time wherever the user is. I know that TI sensors can just use Bluetooth low energy, not wifi. So I'm looking for an intermediate technology capable to retrieve data from sensor and send it to a server (database), and then, my app would just retrieve these data from database. I've read about zigbee and waspmote but these seems not capable to do what I'm looking for, and waspmote is too expensive.
Please, I'm not good in electrical domain, I'm just in software engineering studies, so please just told me about thing that don't need a deep technical configuration.
Thanks for answers

Comment: do questions get any better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to send the Sensor Tag (which communicates over BLE) readings to internet. If thats right, then I have the following suggestion, which I feel may actually solve the problem that you are attempting

1. You would need a gateway that can communicate over BLE (with the sensor), as well as, over Ethernet / Wifi (with a server or an IoT Cloud offering). This gateway could be a device like Raspberry Pi or SimpleLink or a smart phone. Check the [site](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connect-a-cc2650-sensortag-to-the-iot-foundations-quickstart/) which shows this can be done using IBM IoT Foundation Connect and Simple Link.
2. Your phone can next communicate using Wifi or GPRS with the server.

Note that in any of the cases, you will have to procure the gateway. So it definitely is not a zero-cost solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm gonna use the raspberry solution with an node.js server on it to send data through IBM iot cloud. Thanks again!!